# Text parsing a log file effectively in c++

Tags: c++, parsing

I want to build a log browser. For which I need to code effectively. Given is a simple code for parsing. 
Please let me know if this code is okay or any improvements to be given.
Also strtok(o,delim) function in the below given program is not clear. So please explain me about its functionality.

```
// parsing ex.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include <cstring>

const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20;
const char* const DELIMITER = " ";

int main()
{
    // create a file-reading object
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("C:\\Personal\\data.txt"); // open a file
    if (!fin.good()) 
        return 1; // exit if file not found

    // read each line of the file
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        // read an entire line into memory
        char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
        fin.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

        // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
        int n = 0; // a for-loop index

        // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
        const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

        // parse the line
        token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
        if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
        {
            for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
            {
                token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
                if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
            }
        }

        // process (print) the tokens
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
            cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use strtok or other C function when  we have powerful "string" class in c++98 and "regex" in c++11.

Comment: `strtok` is a common function, do a web search for detailed explanation. Documentation is also available [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1990/strings/2557/tokenisation-strtok-strtok-r-and-strtok-s#t=201609190731093043245)

Answer (score 4):

Your code works, except there are no boundary checks. It will fail if a line in the file is longer than `MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE`. `while (!fin.eof()){...}` is prone to other errors as well.

You can easily solve this problem with `std::string`

The code also fails if a line contains more than `MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE` tokens. You can solve this by using `std::vector`

For improvements, use `std::string` instead of character arrays.

Use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

Use `std::stringstream` instead of `strtok`

The advantage is that you don't have to worry about maximum line length, or maximum number of tokens per line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

const char CDELIMITER = ' ';

int main()
{
    ...
    std::string buf;

    //read the file line by line
    while (std::getline(fin, buf))
    {
        //convert the line in to stream:
        std::istringstream ss(buf);

        //declare vector of string (instead of fixed array)
        std::vector<std::string> vec;

        //read the line, word by word
        while (std::getline(ss, buf, CDELIMITER))
            vec.push_back(buf);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
            std::cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << vec[i] << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```